# Online classes on Moreh Nevuchim in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, internet, rambam, english

Does anyone know of English classes online for the Rambam's Moreh Nevuchim?

Comment: They have an English translation online if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Pay sites:

- [Rabbi Wein](http://www.rabbiwein.com/Rambam-Moreh-Nevuchim--Three-Views-of-Jewish-Philosophy-P316.html).

Free sites:

- [Moshe Becker](http://mosheb.posthaven.com/tag/Moreh%20Nevuchim) - audio (downloadable) is under the text of each section.
- [Rabbi Berel Wein](http://wfmu.org/playlists/shows/41334) as part of a radio program.
- [Yeshivat HaKotel](http://www.hakotel.org.il/english/torah/view.asp?id=1799) - intro to Moreh Nevuchim

That's all I found on the first page of a google search for ***Moreh Nevuchim mp3***